# Tyk dashboard app - Couldn't establish a connection with Mongo: no reachable servers

Tags: mongodb, docker, containers, tyk

I am trying to set up a [Tyk dashboard Docker container](https://hub.docker.com/r/tykio/tyk-dashboard/) for an API gateway. There is a configuration file that is used by Tyk to, among other things, connect to a Redis, and Mongo using JSON. I set up a MongoDB cluster using [MongoDB Atlas](https://www.mongodb.com/cloud/atlas). I took the connection string, and put it into the Tyk config JSON for the "mongo_url" key.

```
mongodb://<username>:<password>@cluster0-shard-00-00-to2hv.mongodb.net:27017,cluster0-shard-00-01-to2hv.mongodb.net:27017,cluster0-shard-00-02-to2hv.mongodb.net:27017/admin
```

I can successfully connect to my NoSQL cluster using the MongoDB Compass app, but when I try to run the Tyk Dashboard container, I get an error

> time="Nov  7 20:12:09" level=info msg="connecting to MongoDB:
>   [cluster0-shard-00-00-to2hv.mongodb.net:27017
>   cluster0-shard-00-01-to2hv.mongodb.net:27017
>   cluster0-shard-00-02-to2hv.mongodb.net:27017]"
>
> time="Nov  7 20:12:21"
>   level=fatal msg="Couldn't establish a connection with Mongo: no
>   reachable servers"

Has anyone ever run into this issue before?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe for Atlas you need an ssl connection, have you set `"mongo-use_ssl":true` in the tyk_analytics.conf?

Comment: That was it spiraloutkeepgoing! Thank you : )

Comment: I believe its `mongo_use_ssl`